# Show the error position in Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

How can I get the script error or the position of the error in the script in Jenkins console output?
I use Eclipse, Selenium Webdriver, Testng... for integration test, it's a Java project.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the [BFA plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer), you can define the error pattern firstly, if the error message hits the pattern, you will get a link in the Jenkins report to point out the line that error happened.

Comment: thanks! but sorry I didn't get it. I think it's a matter of script.